# How To Generate Platforms Down Each other in a pattern with some different positions Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am instantiating a platform below one another which you can see in below pic

[image: Platforms Below Each Other]

But I want to generate platforms like this

[image: The pattern what i want]

So how I can do this? Below you can read my code, which generate platforms below each other only in Y position.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class platformGeneration : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numOfPlatforms;
    public GameObject platform;
    public Transform spawnPosition;

// Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        Vector3 pos = spawnPosition.GetComponent<Transform>().position;

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPlatforms; i++)
        {
            spawnPlatofrm(pos + new Vector3(i+2,-i - 5, 0));



            //spawnPlatofrm(pos + new Vector3(0, -i - 5, -i - 2));

            //for (int j = 0; j < numOfPlatforms; j++)
            //{
            //    spawnPlatofrm(pos + new Vector3(0, -j - 5, -j - 2));
            //}

            //spawnPlatofrm(pos + (Vector3.right * i));


        }
    }



    void spawnPlatofrm(Vector3 spawnPosition)
    {
        Instantiate(platform, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write out the positions of the platforms in the pattern you want? It's hard to see exactly what positions they are in from just a single image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing your start method with this:

```
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 pos = spawnPosition.GetComponent<Transform>().position;

        int next = 2;
        int slide = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPlatforms; i++)
        {
            spawnPlatofrm(pos + new Vector3(i+next,-i - 5, slide));
            next *= -1;
            if(next == 2) slide++;
        }
    }
```